# Changing references when running a backup and restore

Tags: sql-server, ssms

We have a database in production that uses views or other resources from other  databases. When we do a back up and restore into our test environment to look at an issue some of the resources are still pointing to that original database. A good example of this might be

In production

```
-- Some important stored procedure that returns thee revenue code, not an actual example part of main application database
SELECT RevenueCode FROM ManagementDatabase.dbo.RevenueCodes
```

When we back it up into test it still have that same refernce

```
    SELECT RevenueCode FROM ManagementDatabase.dbo.RevenueCodes
```

However because this is a shared database and backing up and restoring over it might destroy some new work being added to it.

For that reason we created a database 'ManagementDatabase_Prod' in our testing environment. My question is there any way to automatically change the refernces in one database so that any views/procedures or functions will reference the 'ManagementDatabase_Prod' in test rather than the 'ManagementDatabase' (which is right for production)

I did it manually last time, my other thought would be to script these files out and write a small script to replace them if there's not a built in way to do this.

Comment: You should look into synonyms for this kind of thing. We use them extensively to manage this type of thing. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/synonyms/synonyms-database-engine

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted, never knew it existed.